# Adding a separate string to each item in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a python list as follows:

```
new_list = ['emp_salary', 'manager_sal']
```

I want to change it to below:

```
['emp_salary' : 'float', 'manager_sal':'float']
```

I tried something like this:

```
    >>> users_cols = [l+ ": float" for l in new_list]
   >>> users_cols
       ['emp_salary: float', 'manager_sal: float']
```

But it is not exactly what i want. The actual list is very big and this is a small example

Comment: your desired output is not valid Python. What are you trying to do?

Comment: `['emp_salary' : 'float', 'manager_sal':'float']` isn't valid Python syntax. Do you actually want `{'emp_salary': 'float', 'manager_sal': 'float'}`?

Comment: Are you trying to create a dictionary object `{'emp_salary' : 'float', 'manager_sal':'float'}`?

Comment: That is right. I want a dictionary eventually.

Comment: You can do `dict.fromkeys(new_list, 'float')`

Comment: I'm curious what you're going to do with this dictionary. Depending on your actual use case, you may find `{'emp_salary': float, 'manager_sal': float}` more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completedness:

```
new_list = ['emp_salary', 'manager_sal']    
new_dict = dict.fromkeys(new_list, "float")
```

Beware that this will work only if you want to have the same value for each of the keys. Do not use this to declare your mutable values (like sets, lists, dictionaries...), tho unless you want them to all point to the same instance.

Comment: Indeed. For example, `dict.fromkeys(new_list, [])` will make all the `dict` values be the same `list`, which is generally undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to properly define and initialize a dictionary:

```
new_list = ['emp_salary', 'manager_sal']
users_cols = {}
for key in new_list:
    users_cols[key] = 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = ['emp_salary', 'manager_sal']
new_dict = {key: 'float' for key in new_list}
```

Answer (score 1):

In list there is no such thing you need *dictionary* for this, which stores key-value pair:

```
users_col = { key: "float" for key in new_list }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_list = ['emp_salary', 'manager_sal']

final_dict = dict(map(lambda x: (x, "float"), new_list))
```